# Trying to parse a html with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, parsing

I am very new to the community, nice to be here.

Recently I have been trying to learn by doing to parse some htmls with Excel VBA, I am successful in some webs, however, fail in some others. And one of the html got the text below:

```
<div class="commodity-list clearfix">
<dl dlproid="39632197" class="">
<div class="show_tips">
<dt id="propic_39632197" data="">
<a href="http://item.secoo.com/39632197.shtml?source=list" onclick="analytical('搜索页18','商品');" target="_blank" title="LOEWE/罗意威 19年秋冬 女包 女性 手提包 38730S35 BLACK"><img data-original="http://pic11.secooimg.com/product/240/240/2020/0120/8e2e16c7d5c5471a980e659318c16ba9.jpg" src="http://pic11.secooimg.com/product/240/240/2020/0120/8e2e16c7d5c5471a980e659318c16ba9.jpg" alt="LOEWE/罗意威 19年秋冬 女包 女性 手提包 38730S35 BLACK图片" width="240" height="240" style="display: inline;"></a></dt>
<dd class="dl_size clearfix" style="display: none;"></dd>       
<dd class="dl_tips">
<span class="s1">欧洲</span><span class="s1">自营</span><span class="s2">NEW</span></dd>
<dd class="dl_name">
<a href="http://item.secoo.com/39632197.shtml?source=list" id="name_39632197" target="_blank" title="LOEWE/罗意威 19年秋冬 女包 女性 手提包 38730S35 BLACK" onclick="analytical('搜索页18','商品');">LOEWE/罗意威 19年秋冬 女包 女性 手提包 38730S35 BLACK<span class="subtitle"></span></a></dd>
<dd class="dl_price clearfix">
<span id="secoo_price_39632197"><i>￥</i>14269</span></dd>
<dd class="add_cart">
<a href="javascript:;" id="add_to_cart_39632197" proid="39632197" onclick="addToCart(event,'list');analytical('搜索页19','加入购物车');">加入购物车</a>
<span class="deal-cnt" id="dealCnt_39632197" style="">仅剩1件</span>
</dd>
<span class="loveHeart" id="love_heart_39632197" parentid="39632197" loveid="39632197" onclick="analytical('列表','列表_收藏');"><i>收藏</i></span>
<span class="tipState" id="tipSate_39632197" style="display:none;">已加入购物车</span>
</div>
</dl>
<dl dlproid="21795393" class="">
<div class="show_tips">
<dt id="propic_21795393" data="">
<a href="http://item.secoo.com/21795393.shtml?source=list" onclick="analytical('搜索页18','商品');" target="_blank" title="COACH/蔻驰 女士牛皮时尚手提挎包 36855 DKLMF"><img data-original="http://pic11.secooimg.com/product/240/240/10/53/e5d300ec36e2438c8b46226eae22f730.jpg" src="http://pic11.secooimg.com/product/240/240/10/53/e5d300ec36e2438c8b46226eae22f730.jpg" alt="COACH/蔻驰 女士牛皮时尚手提挎包 36855 DKLMF图片" width="240" height="240" style="display: inline;"></a></dt>
<dd class="dl_size clearfix" style="display: none;"></dd>       
<dd class="dl_tips">
<span class="s1">自营</span><span class="s2">直降</span></dd>
<dd class="dl_name">
<a href="http://item.secoo.com/21795393.shtml?source=list" id="name_21795393" target="_blank" title="COACH/蔻驰 女士牛皮时尚手提挎包 36855 DKLMF" onclick="analytical('搜索页18','商品');">COACH/蔻驰 女士牛皮时尚手提挎包 36855 DKLMF<span class="subtitle"></span></a></dd>
<dd class="dl_price clearfix">
<span id="secoo_price_21795393"><i>￥</i>2711</span></dd>
<dd class="add_cart">
<a href="javascript:;" id="add_to_cart_21795393" proid="21795393" onclick="addToCart(event,'list');analytical('搜索页19','加入购物车');">加入购物车</a>
<span class="deal-cnt" id="dealCnt_21795393" style="display:none;">仅剩3件</span>
</dd>
<span class="loveHeart" id="love_heart_21795393" parentid="21795393" loveid="21795393" onclick="analytical('列表','列表_收藏');"><i>收藏</i></span>
<span class="tipState" id="tipSate_21795393" style="display:none;">已加入购物车</span>
</div>
</dl>
```

I tried to parse it with VBA code shown below:

```
Sub ParseS()
Dim http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, topic As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim ProductInfos As Object, ProductInfo As HTMLHtmlElement
Dim i As Integer
Dim page As Double

    Url = Cells(2, 3).Value

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", Url, False
    http.send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

    Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("show_tips")

        i = Cells(4, 1).Value

        For Each topic In topics    

            Set ProductInfos = topic.getElementsByTagName("dt")(0)

            For Each ProductInfo In ProductInfos

            Sheets("parse").Cells(6 + i, 3).Value = ProductInfo.getAttribute("id")

            Next

            i = i + 1
        Next

End Sub
```

As shown I realized the info I wanted are under every class "show_tips" so I try to get them with getElementsByClassName, then I go to the children tag /dt and wanna the id no.(which I understand is the attribute), after this I run the code and it comes out with nothing, not even an error. It just loaded and showed nothing.

I believe there is something wrong, thought I have tried similar codes to parse some other htmls and  run the code and it comes out with nothing, not even an error. It just loaded and showed nothing.

I believe there is something wrong, thought I have tried similar codes to parse some other htmls and they were successful, I don't know what happen with this.

Hope to get help, thanks!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code, to make sure the collections are being populated?

Comment: Is the url of a Chinese trading platform a secret?